# how can i list directories and its files using Nginx?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, nginx, phalcon

I want to list directories and it's files like

```
/Index
      /Directories 1
       1) File1.php
          File2.php
          File3.php
      /Directories 2
       1) File1.php
          File2.php
          File3.php
```

And so on.

Answer (score 4):

Add below in your server module

```
location / { 
    autoindex on; 
}
```

，and delete the line or comment

`#index index.html index.php;`

Finally, restart your Nginx.

```
service nginx reload
```